# python how to close TCP connections in pyrogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyrogram

I'am doing a pyrogram connection multiple times:

```
        client_pyro = Client(
            ":memory:",
            session_string=session_string,
            api_id=app_id,
            api_hash=api_hash,
            takeout=True,
            no_updates=True,
            sleep_threshold=5,
            proxy=getpyroproxyobject(proxy_index)
        )
```

after this there is connection:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTBXP.png)

then i do:

```
client_pyro.disconnect()
```

but the connections dont close, they are still there hanging, so the question is how can i close all those TCP connections via python or pyrogram methods, but in pyrogram i didnt found any options for that neither any description about this case

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the documentation and found `Client.terminate()`.
If you want the doc url is https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/terminate.
I hope this has helped you.

Comment: tried the terminate and the processess are still hanging